# How can i call a dart class when it is initiated?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to create an instance of a class and automatically call an init method all in one line. At the moment I can only do it in two lines which I don't want to do? In javascript/react it wpould be like the constructor method???

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

// @immutable
class StyleModel {
  TextStyle pageTitle;

  final Color primaryColor = Color.fromRGBO(253, 34, 00, 1.0); //Red

  StyleModel();

  void init() {

    this.pageTitle =
        TextStyle(color: primaryColor);
  }
}

var style = StyleModel();
style.init();
```

I'd like to just create an instance of the class and it be called using the private properties assigned to build up other properties of the class??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the cascade operator for that case `StyleModel()..primaryColor = Colors.red;`
That allows you to add operations in "cascade". Check this for more info [Here](https://news.dartlang.org/2012/02/method-cascades-in-dart-posted-by-gilad.html)

Comment: Perfect. That was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you :) I just needed to add the init to the constructor:

var style = (StyleModel()..init())